# PHP json_decode not getting code from variable

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with the build in `json_decode()` function in PHP. I have the followig json file:

```
{
    "var1":"data1",
    "var2":"data2",
    "var3":"data3",
    "snippet":"<?php\n\necho \"hello world\";"
}
```

I want to save the code in a json file for multiple reasons but `json_decode()` doesn't want to output it.
Here is the code I use for getting the data:

```
$str_data = file_get_contents("json_files/".$new.".json");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);
```

And later I just simply use this to get all the data:

```
echo $data['snippet'];
```

This works just fine with var1/var2/var2 but doesn't with the code.

Comment: how exactly doesn't it work? meaning: what is the output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: `<?php ` will in an echo statement probably be interpereted as the start of an HTML tag and therefore you can't  "see it". Try "View Source", I bet's there.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The expected output should be something like: <?php echo "hello world"; (with breaks) but I'm getting just two blank lines...

Comment: @Repox I'm not seeing the <?php in the source code and if I change the code to e.g. HTML it is working.

Comment: @Marnix Bouhuis could not reproduce, i'm seeing the tags in my local source. probably some exotic server configuration? PLUS: what's the output of var_dump($data);

Comment: @FranzGleichmann See it for your self, try write some code and then same it: https://codepost.ga/56a1d9f3832d5

Comment: Did you try `echo htmlentities($data['snippet']);`?

Comment: @Marnix Bouhuis try to execute your code on an actual server, and not on a code testing service like this, I would bet that it is some kind of output-sanitation from codepost.

Comment: Do you create the json in the first place using `json_encode`? What options have you set for that? `json_encode( $data,JSON_HEX_TAG)`??

Comment: u cant handle it, i suggest u to replace with empty and than add in snippet variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to execute PHP scripts from a string, you can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
However keep in mind that function can be dangerous if you don't sanitize your data properly.

Your current code does not work as it is a string and the PHP interpreter does pick it up as a script tag but comments it out cause of security reasons and thus its only shown in the source code of the html page.

Edit as by comment below:

```
$json = '{
  "var1":"data1",
  "var2":"data2",
  "var3":"data3",
  "snippet":"<?php\n\necho \"hello world\";"
}';

echo htmlentities(json_decode($json)->snippet);
echo htmlentities(json_decode($json, true)['snippet']);
echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', json_decode($json, true)['snippet']);

// Choose your method.. all works.
```

Comment: Then you should use `htmlentites()` and next time be clear on what you ask.

Answer (score 2):

Testing the following:

```
<?php
$str_data = '
{
    "var1":"data1",
    "var2":"data2",
    "var3":"data3",
    "snippet":"<?php\n\necho \"hello world\";"
}';

$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

echo $data['snippet'];
```

gives me the following output:

```
<?php

echo "hello world";
```

If you're viewing this in the browser, you are probably not seeing it because the browser reads is as HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$json = '{
"var1":"data1",
"var2":"data2",
"var3":"data3",
"snippet":"?php\n\necho \"hello world\";"
}';
$data = json_decode($json);
header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo $data->snippet;
?>
```

I tried with above code. After some time found out.. "<" is causing problem for php tag.

Well i think you cannot get away with this

Answer (score -1):

use var_dump to see the data is correct?

```js
$str_data = file_get_contents("json_files/".$new.".json");
var_dump($str_data);
```